# rails object to memcached and then out again

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, ruby-on-rails-3, memcached, deserialization

I want to store a simple active record object using memcached.  I know I need to first convert the object to JSON before saving it to memcached my question is how I can pull it out again, deserialize it and use it as an activerecord relation.  Do I have to make a custom parser the JSON or am I overlooking some drop dead easy solution?

The active record object looks like this:

```
+------+-----+-----------+---------------------------------+---------------------+-------+
| id   | ppl | exclusive | name                            | price               | spots |
+------+-----+-----------+---------------------------------+---------------------+-------+
| 8948 | 12  | false     | 12 Bed Mixed Dorm               | 9.0000000000000000  | 12    |
| 8947 | 10  | false     | 10 Bed Mixed Dorm               | 9.5000000000000000  | 10    |
| 8946 | 6   | false     | 6 Bed Mixed Dorm                | 10.0000000000000000 | 6     |
| 8945 | 4   | false     | Basic 4 Bed Mixed Dorm          | 10.0000000000000000 | 4     |
| 8944 | 2   | true      | Twin Private Shared Bathroom    | 12.0000000000000000 | 1     |
| 8943 | 1   | true      | Standard Single Private Ensuite | 15.0000000000000000 | 1     |
+------+-----+-----------+---------------------------------+---------------------+-------+
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't don't need to worry about the serialization -- in almost all cases, this can be handled for you:

```
#Gemfile
gem install dalli

#config/environments/production.rb
config.cache_store = :dalli_store, '127.0.0.1' #use memcached

#Get id 1245 from model_names
Rails.cache.fetch("ModelName#1245") do
  ModelName.find(1245)
end
```

Comment: not sure what was going on, but doing .to_a on my non rails model beforehand did the trick.